# Array Pseudocode confusion

Tags: pseudocode, notation

I am trying to implement the CYK algorithm. I had a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) for it, the pseudocode it provides has the following notation for arrays.

```
P[n, n, r]
```

I am used to seeing arrays written with like `P[n]`, what does the above notation mean?

Comment: That denotes a multi dimensional array. You can think of it as `Array[Array[Array[something]]]`

Comment: 3D array, check the algorithm as it has more instance for the same